# Getting error while installing .ipa file and provision profile through iTunes on another ipad and mac

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode6, app-store-connect

I am adding devices UDID into provision profile and sending this to other mac for installation on another iPad. If I try to install .ipa through iTunes on that mac, it gets an error "The iPad could not be synced because this computer is no longer authorised for purchased items that are on this iPad" but this computer is already authorised.

Comment: are you sending provisioning profile ?

Comment: @DevangGoswami Yes I send provision profile with his UDID.

Comment: ok , why dont you send ipa instead provisioning profile

Comment: @DevangGoswami:I sending both provision and ipa

Comment: then do one thing create a development cert from another mac and with that cert create provisioning and run on device

Comment: @DevangGoswami:thanks and finally install testing build to other ipad using http://www.diawi.com

Comment: more safly use testFlight .. which is more relevent then this

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using Xcode in installing the .ipa in the device? Open Xcode then Go to Window>Devices. Select your device then click the '+' button in the bottom. Select the .ipa file.